# Detecting whether a folder is in a directory or not.

Tags: python, git

I want to make sure a folder whose name is known is in a specific directory or not. the directory that I want to check is   my git repository. Assume that my git repository directory is `/home/cmp/Desktop/GIT_REFERENCE_REPOSITORIES` and I want to detect the folder namely `'test'` is in there or not.

Is there anyone who can help me ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your looking for is [`os.path.exists(path)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) and [`os.path.isdir(path)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir) to check if a particular path exists and points to a directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/home/cmp/Desktop/GIT_REFERENCE_REPOSITORIES'):
   dirs[:] = [os.path.join(root, d) for d in dirs]

for dir in dirs:
    if dir.endswith("test"):
         print "test is in dirs"
```

Comment: thanks for reply. Now another question . git directory is not constant actually.So first of all I have to find directory of git repository and than give it to os.walk. How could I do that

Comment: reference_repositories_path="cat $HOME/.git_reference_repositories | sed 's/GIT_REFERENCES_PATH=//'"
 test=os.system(reference_repositories_path) . I tried this but did not work

Comment: is it an environmental variable?

Comment: I couldnt understand your question  ? @amadain

Comment: from http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html os.environ

    A mapping object representing the string environment. For example, environ['HOME'] is the pathname of your home directory (on some platforms), and is equivalent to getenv("HOME") in C.

Comment: if you type in echo $GIT_REFERENCES_PATH what do you get?

Comment: when I wrote it terminal, nothing Its a name of my gitrepository

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36710/discussion-between-amadain-and-eday)